# Can not create duplicate detection rule for Product entity

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

Can anyone explain to me why the product entity is not in the base entity type when creating a duplicate detection rule. I have googled this but could not find any information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you have enabled duplicate detection against the Product entity.
Inside the Product entity customization, under Data Services section, check if Duplicate Detection is selected.

This must be selected for you to see the Product in the list of base entities inside the Duplicate Detection Rule dialog window.